# Pygame: How do I get KEYDOWN to input only once?

Tags: python, pygame

Hi I'm creating a game where I have multiple stages. I want to make it so that every time the user presses the key `a`, the next stage will trigger. Here is a sample of my code.

```
gameStage = 0 ## outside while loop

##INSIDE whileloop
if gameStage == 0:
    ##insert drawings,music, etc
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
       if event.key == pygame.K_a:
            gameStage += 1

if gameStage == 1:
    ##insert drawings,music, etc
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
       if event.key == pygame.K_a:
            gameStage += 1
```

my problem is that when the user presses the `a` key, `a` will be input more than once depending how long the key is held. Therefore, it will just skip all the way to my last stage. How do I make it so that the `gameStage` is +=1 only when the key has been pressed AND lifted? Please tell me if I'm being unclear. Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: What about using key up instead?

Comment: Where is your `for event in pygame.event.get():` loop at the moment? With your current code layout it looks like you need a separate event loop in each stage.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `pygame.KEYUP` event.

e.g.

`if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:`

But you should not be getting repeated `KEYDOWN` messages, unless you have called `pygame.key.set_repeat` and set a non zero repeat value.

The fact that you get the repeated increments of `GameStage` even when you capture only `KEYUP` messages would indicate that there is some other issue in your code.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but doesn't KEYUP simply mean that the key is up? and not that it is released? If i'm right, this doesn't solve anything. It will just skip through all the stages when the key remains up. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: No, you should only get a single KEYUP event, when the key is released. You only get multiple KEYDOWN events as a key repeat mechanism. If it were as you suggest, you'd permanently be getting KEYUP messages for all the keys you don't have pressed.

Comment: No idea what I'm doing wrong. Im using the key.up event yet I still get the same problem. I used the exact template i provided above with KEYDOWN replaced with KEYUP. Still skipping through the stages. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Check your indentation. Then put a few prints in to see what course the code is following.

Comment: Do you call `pygame.key.set_repeat` anywhere in your code? If not then you should not be getting key repeats anyway. This indicates the error is in your code.

Comment: That's not true, since the `pygame.KEYDOWN` event appears *only once* on the event queue when a key is pressed. So you don't need to listen for any `pygame.KEYUP` events!

Comment: @elegent I'm not sure if you followed the comments, but I think we came to that conclusion and now I'm waiting for the OP to check his code, since there is clearly another issue.

Comment: @PaulRooney: Yes sorry you are right, I didn't read them... I only posted this because of your answer :)

Comment: @elegent I made an edit, to ensure it's clearer. People shouldn't have to read comments to get an answer :D

Answer (score 1):

When keyboard buttons are pressed or released **a `pygame.KEDOWN` or `pygame.KEYUP` event appears only ones on the event queue**<sup>1</sup>

As you did, you need to set a global variable `GameStage`, which indicates the current game state:

```
GameStage = 0 ## outside while loop
```

After this we run our main game loop and fetch all events form the even queue using the [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) function, which reads and removes events from the queue:

```
while True:
    #get all events from the  event queue
    for ev in pygame.event.get():
```

If the read event represents a key-down-event of <kbd>a</kbd> the program logic updates the `GameStage` variable, similar to a so-called [*state-machine*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine):

```
if ev.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    if ev.key == pygame.K_a:            
        if GameStage == 0:
            GameStage += 1
            #do something

        elif GameStage == 1:
            GameStage += 1
            #do something great

        # and so on ;)
```

---

The complete program block looks like this:

```
#global variable GameStage for state-machine
GameStage = 0 

#main game loop
while True:
    #get all events from the  event queue
    for ev in pygame.event.get():
        if ev.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if ev.key == pygame.K_a:            
                if GameStage == 0:
                    GameStage += 1
                    #do something 

                elif GameStage == 1:
                    GameStage += 1
                    #do something great

                elif GameStage == 2:
                    GameStage += 1
                    #do something great again

                elif GameStage == 3:
                    #this is the last stage, so you cloud go back to stage #0
                    GameStage = 0

                #for debugging print current GameStage 
                print(GameStage)
```

Only when you press -- no matter how long you hold down -- <kbd>a</kbd> the `GameStage` will be updated only once.

Hope this helps :)

<sup>1</sup> As @sloth noted, this can be changed be calling [`pygame.key.set_repeat()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.set_repeat), which will generate *multiple* `pygame.KEYDOWN` events when keys are held down.

Comment: `...event appears only ones on the event queue`: This is generally true, but only if you don't enable key repetition with `pygame.key.set_repeat` (which is bad most of the times).

Comment: @sloth: Fair enough :) I will add that, because this could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use key up event, as suggested above, or stop reacting to keydown event for a few ticks after it was issued.

Comment: How would I stop reacting to the keydown event for a few ticks?

Comment: Like this:
`ticks_to_ignore = 0
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and ticks_to_ignore == 0:
    ticks_to_ignore = 10
    # Process event

# Elsewhere in the main loop
if ticks_to_ignore > 0:
    ticks_to_ignore -= 1`

But it's a bit of an ugly hack, keyup would probably be easier and more obvious to the player.